# SUMIFS with Multiple Criteria with Multiple Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

There are certain situations where SUMIFS returns values I do not expect when there are multiple criteria.  Can you help me understand what is going on here and how I can get the expected result?

This screenshot shows the data I am using, the values I get, and the values I expected to get:

[image]

The data is in a table called "Table1".  Here are the four formulas I am using:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table1[Value],Table1[Letter],{"A","B"},Table1[Greek],{"Alpha"}))
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table1[Value],Table1[Letter],{"A","B"},Table1[Greek],{"Kappa"}))
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table1[Value],Table1[Letter],{"A","B"},Table1[Greek],{"Alpha","Beta","Kappa"}))
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table1[Value],Table1[Letter],{"A","B"},Table1[Greek],{"Alpha","Kappa"}))
```

The first two statements work as expected, but when I add multiple options in the second "criteria" then the numbers don't add as I expect them to.

In the third statement, for example, I would expect that it adds up the first four rows (everything with (Letter A or B) AND (Greek of Alpha, Beta, or Kappa)) which would total 70.  Instead it comes back with 10.

Using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using two arrays in a sumifs, one must be vertical while the other horizontal:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table1[Value],Table1[Letter],{"A","B"},Table1[Greek],{"Alpha";"Beta";"Kappa"}))
```

The `,` denotes the horizontal, while the `;` denotes a vertical array.

So since there is no depth or 3rd dimension to a range of cells the most one formula can have is two arrays in the criteria.

Comment: The semi-colons do give me the expected outcome!  Two follow-up questions:Are you saying that if I had another column called Fruit, I would not be able to add a third criteria that says only give me Apples and Bananas?

Comment: That is correct, It will not work with more than two.

Comment: Second follow-up: Can you help me understand how it got to "10" as a value?

Comment: It did a one for one.  It iterated both arrays at the same time so only the pairs "A" and "Alpha","B" and "Beta", "" and "Kappa"  The only one that matched one of those pairs was "A" and "Alpha" which was 10.

Comment: Please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.